# SQL Server Triggers and Access Linked Tables

Tags: sql-server, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2013

We use Microsoft Access as our front end with a SQL Server back end.  We have forms in Access bound to linked tables in the SQL server database.

Recently, there has been a request made to track data changes on quite a bit of our SQL Server tables.

I found an article that describes how to create triggers against these tables to audit all changes in a separate table.

After implementing these triggers, I have found an issue with the Access forms.  After the Access form inserts a row of data, the data is inserted correctly into the database, but the record on the form appears to be switching to a random existing record and not staying on the record that is being inserted.

Is there an acceptable work around for getting Access forms to bind correctly with linked SQL Server tables that have triggers attached to them?

I've seen this behavior on both Access 2007 and 2013.

Comment: Just a quick thought: The problem is probably linked to Access using @@identity to query the ID of the added record. But meanwhile your trigger has generated a different ID in the audit-tables. Maybe you can work around that by not using identity-columns in your audit tables.

Comment: Yes, that does appear to resolve the issue.  Thank you.